# Where does Android store dynamic module APKs?

Tags: android, adb, android-app-bundle

I'm working on an android app with [dynamic modules](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#dynamic_feature_modules). Let assume there is one base module (`base`) and one dynamic module (`feature`). I installed the app using Android Studio (or [bundle tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool)) and both `base` and `feature` apks were installed and located in

```
/data/app/example.dynapp--Gn1-FdAo0qV-8Y8Q5qb7g==/base.apk
/data/app/example.dynapp--Gn1-FdAo0qV-8Y8Q5qb7g==/feature.apk
```

I found these addresses by running

```
adb shell pm path example.dynapp
```

Then I uploaded the app bundle on Play Console and installed it from Google Play on my phone. Next, I downloaded the `feature` module when I was using the app. However, after I run `adb shell pm path example.dynapp` it only shows the `base` apk and there is no sign for `feature` apk. By the way, 
it seems the `feature` module is installed since the functionality of `feature` module works correctly.

My question is where does Google Play keep these dynamic loaded modules (or APKs). And is there any way to access them using `adb` (such as `adb pull`).

Comment: Did you find any solution? i am too, stuck as to where the downloaded dynamic module's data would be saved because right now the app size itself didn't increase much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it stores it in application dir.

like this:

```
/data/data/com.myapp.mypackage/files/splitcompat/1400191/verified-splits/kotlin.config.xxhdpi.apk
```

obviously, 1400191 changes.

In order to locate your apk files which are downloaded, you could probably run the linux command on the device to find them:

```
find / -name *.xxhdpi.apk
```

or even better:

```
find /data/data/com.myapp.mypackage -name *.xxhdpi.apk
```

Note: you need to run these after 'adb shell', after that, you need to run as your application.
If you have a rooted device, then typing 'su' will be sufficient after 'adb shell'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just adding one point: if the device is not rooted, the base APK must be debuggable (you can use internal app sharing in Play store to upload a debuggable version of your app bundle). Then, run the following commands: `adb shell` -> `run-as PKG_NAME` -> `find . -name "*.apk"` The output is the list of installed dynamic feature modules.

Comment: Good point. Running on a rooted device made me forgot that :)